# Fullscreen Video Pushing the NavBar upwards to the size of the status bar and remains there after exit Fullscreen

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

the problem is when the user switch to fullscreen video and then coming back the NavBar of the NavigationWindow is pushed upwards to the size of the status bar and remains there.

The only solution for me that worked is to close and reopen the MainNavigationWindow. and this couldn't be the final solution.

more hint's from me:
z-index of the Video View is higher than the others.
fullscreen vor the app and hiding the NavBar and StatusBar is disabled in the tiapp.xml.
fullscreen for the MainNavigationWindow and it's Main Window is disabled in the
.tss Files.

It looks like this will be all ignored.
The Fullscreen Signal from the VideoPlayer is fired and pushes the navbar to the size of the status bar upward.
After the fullscreen exit remains the navbar at the position.
And under the navbar remains a black gap in the size of the StatusBar.

Screenshots [>> here <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xelG7.jpg)

Same Problem [>> here <<](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/182527/nav-bar-shrinks-after-returning-from-full-screen-video-on-ios-83) on the Appcelerator Website asked 5 months ago. (with no solution)

---

MainWindow

```
<Alloy>
<NavigationWindow id="mainNavigationWindow" platform="ios">
<Window id="mainWindow" class="container">
<Require src="webview" id="startWindowWebViewView"/>
<Require src="videoPlayer" id="startWindowVideoPlayerView"/>
<Require src="menu" id="startWindowMenuView"/>
</Window>
</NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

---

View

```
<Alloy>
<View id="videoPlayerContainer" class="container">
<VideoPlayer id="videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer" />
</View>
</Alloy>
```

---

TSS

```
"#videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer":{
    height:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    borderWidth: 1,
    zIndex: 1,
    visible: false,
    mediaControlStyle: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_EMBEDDED,
    scalingMode: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
    autoplay: false
}
```

---

Controller

```
function hideVideoPlayer() {
$.videoPlayerContainer.setVisible(false);
$.videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer.setSourceType(Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE_UNKNOWN);
}

function setVideoPlayerMedia(media) {
$.videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer.setSourceType(Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE_UNKNOWN);
$.videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer.setSourceType(Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE_FILE);
$.videoPlayerContainer.setVisible(true);
$.videoPlayerContainerVideoPlayer.setMedia(media);

}
```

Comment: This is also happening to me, but without videos. I have a window with navbar. Then open a FullScreen window. Close this window and the previous one shrinks the navbar to the status.
This is iOS only, and I'm using SDK 3.5.1.GA

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I'll create a Jira ticket for this . Meanwhile, I've developed two workarounds resolve or bypass this error.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I've developed two workarounds resolve or bypass this error.

First one (Hide the status bar permanently in the app.)

tiapp.xml (add key: UIStatusBarHidden value: true)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
</ti:app>
```

---

The Second one (Reload the NavigationWindow on leaving the Fullscreen)
Quick example:

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener('fullscreen', function(e) {

    if (e.entering == 0) {
        Ti.API.info("Get out of fullscreen");

        playbackTime = videoPlayer.getCurrentPlaybackTime();
        playing = videoPlayer.getPlaying();

        // Fixes The MenuBar Gap
        Alloy.Globals.mainNavigationWindow.close();
        Alloy.Globals.mainNavigationWindow.open();

        // Wait until Video is ready
        while (videoPlayer.getLoadState() != 3) {}

        // set initial Start time to last play time
        videoPlayer.setCurrentPlaybackTime(playbackTime);

        // checks if the Video was playing
        if (playing) {
            Ti.API.info("start playing again");
            videoPlayer.play();
        }
    } else {
        Ti.API.info("Get in fullscreen");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a valid bug. Please [check](https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20TIMOB%20AND%20text%20~%20%22fullscreen%20video%22%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20resolution%20ASC) if it is a known issue you can watch or else [create](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) a ticket with reproducible steps/environment/code so we can reproduce and fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll create a Jira ticket , since I have no suitable open ticket found.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still look for a solution like me, an alternative solution is to stream your video through a local HTML5 player and open it with a web view, that's the best solution i've found for this problem until it's fixed.